# Heroku removing certs not working with error

Tags: ssl, heroku

I'm trying to remove a certificate or to update on Heroku without success doing the command:

```
heroku certs:remove --endpoint -a heroku-app-ssl
```

Error:

> Error: Unexpected argument: heroku-app-ssl

standing on the documentation the `-a heroku-app-ssl` is about my Heroku app name which is that way above but giving me errors so I don't understand what is wrong.

I need to remove old certificate and put a new one but this error blocked me.

I followed this doc:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the `-a` out:

```
heroku certs:remove --endpoint heroku-app-ssl
```

It isn't included in the documentation you referenced.

If you get an error about needing `-a` that probably indicates that you've got multiple Heroku apps connected to this repository, e.g. a staging and a production app. In that case you can add the `-a`, but you need to provide the app name (not the SSL domain) separately:

```
heroku certs:remove --endpoint heroku-app-ssl -a heroku-app
```

You may already be doing this, but I also urge you to move to the [newer Heroku SSL](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl) service. It's free, and much simpler than the old SSL Endpoint paid add-on.